# Force listview item to navigate to a specific page

Tags: javascript, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, winjs

I'm using a grid view application ... what I want to do is to when I invoke a specific item navigate to a specific page.

here is the code when I invoke an item 
**my problem is I can't get the index of an item .**
a figure explain what I mean 
http://www.flickr.com/photos/magedelgazzar/8409848728/in/photostream

```
        _itemInvoked: function (args) {
            var group = Data.groups.getAt(args.detail.itemIndex);
            var item  = Data.items.getAt(args.detail.itemIndex);

            if (appView.value === appViewState.snapped) {
                // If the page is snapped, the user invoked a group.
                this.navigateToGroup(group.key);
            } else {
                // If the page is not snapped, the user invoked an item.
                if ( item.index == 1 && group.index == 2 ) {
                    nav.navigate("../../nextPage.html", { item: Data.getItemReference(item) });

//                nav.navigate("../../nextPage.html");
                }
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: welcome on stackoverflow! Please expand a bit you question in order to expain better what have you done and what you tried to do.

Comment: I'm using a grid template ... I want to navigate to a new page like "about.html" Not related to the groupedItems from a specific item.

Comment: here is what I mean 
http://www.flickr.com/photos/magedelgazzar/8409848728/in/photostream
and thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `args.detail.itemIndex` that you've already used for the items index. This is the right way to get the index; the item you're getting from the `getAt` call is your data item, which unless you've put an `index` on it, won't have an `index` property.

Comment: ok that's works fine .. thank you. but if I need to get the group index also what should I do ?